# use Kustomize to create additional namespaces with a suffix

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Just currently battling an issue with kustomize and not having much look.

I have my config setup and are using kustomize (v4.5.7) to have separate base, variants and environment configuration.  I’m trying to use the setup to deploy a copy of my dev environment onto the same cluster using different namespaces and a suffix.

The idea is that everything would be deployed using a suffix for the name (and got this working but it only does the names and not the namespaces) and drop them into separate namespaces with a suffix.

I’m currently defining all the namspaces with the following config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: mynamespace
```

Now i want to be able to deploy copies of the NS named `mynamespace-mysuffix`

I’ve managed to implemented a suffix for the names of the object alongside a `PrefixSuffixTransformer` to update the namespaces in the objects created to `mynamespace-mysuffix`

This unfortunately doesn’t update the namespace configuration and leaves things in tact.  In short it tries to deploy the objects into namespaces that do not exist.

This is the working `PrefixSuffixTransformer` amending the namespace set in the various objects:

```
apiVersion: builtin
kind: PrefixSuffixTransformer
metadata:
  name: customSuffixer
suffix: "-mysuffix"
fieldSpecs:
  - path: metadata/name
  - path: metadata/namespace
```

trying to target the namespace objects unsuccessfully with the following additional PrefixSuffixTransformer

```
apiVersion: builtin
kind: PrefixSuffixTransformer
metadata:
  name: nsSuffixer
suffix: "-mysuffix"
fieldSpecs:
- kind: Namespace 
  path: metadata/name
```

Was hoping on this last part working but no success.  Anyone any suggestions as to how I can get the additional namespaces created with a suffix?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the solution is just to add a `namespace:` declaration to the `kustomization.yaml` file in your variants.

For example, if I have a `base` directory that contains:

1. `namespace.yaml`

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Namespace
   metadata:
     name: example
   spec: {}
   ```
2. `service.yaml`

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: example
   spec:
     ports:
     - name: http
       port: 80
       targetPort: http
   ```
3. `kustomization.yaml`

   ```
   apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
   kind: Kustomization
   namespace: example

   resources:
     - namespace.yaml
     - service.yaml
   ```

And I create a variant in `overlays/example`, with this `kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: example-mysuffix
resources:
- ../../base

nameSuffix: -mysuffix
```

Then running `kustomize build overlays/example` results in:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: example
spec: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-mysuffix
  namespace: example
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
```

As you have described in your question, the Namespace resource wasn't renamed by the `nameSuffix` configuration. But if I simply add a `namespace:` declaration to the `kustomization.yaml`, like this:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: example-mysuffix
resources:
- ../../base

nameSuffix: -mysuffix
```

Then I get the desired output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: example-mysuffix
spec: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-mysuffix
  namespace: example-mysuffix
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
```

Comment: The above solution would work but would result in all the resources being placed in the same namespace.

In this scenario, I have 4 applications within the base folder, each within their own namespace.  

This is why i am trying to suffix what is already there so we end up with duplicate namespaces on the same cluster.  

So two sets of the same apps/environment on one cluster.